# Translation of "desarrollo integral"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

What is the best English translation for the Spanish phrase *desarrollo integral* (as applied to a person or country)? "Complete development" doesn't sound right, and I can't find the phrase in my dictionary.

Comment: Just found [this](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?query=%22desarrollo+integral%22) which gives several possible translations. I like "holistic development" when applied to people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO the literal translation works

> integral development

I know search results are not a perfect  index but that gives a good idea about its usage. This translation gives 25 million+ (1 million for literal search) results on google.

Now there is another translation I can think of but it doesn't have the exact same meaning only the same idea. As with most of translations one has to conform on translating the rough meaning or idea, as literal translations are not always possible or appropriate.

> complete development

or

> All-inclusive development

These two don't sound very natural, specially complete development as you say. If I were in your shoes I'd use integral development in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I often use "*comprehensive*" as a translation of the Spanish "integral", so "***comprehensive development***" could work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The term I would use is "internal development." As opposed to development brought about, or "forced" from the outside.